# Graph API calendar endpoint doesn't support sending Adaptive card as attachment

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, adaptive-cards, microsoft-graph-calendar, outlook-calendar

We are using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events for creating Calendar events. What we are trying to achieve additionally is to send an adaptive card as attachment. We are using below code as POST body

```
{
"subject": null,
"body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<attachment id=\"74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5\"></attachment>"
},
"attachments": [
    {
        "id": "74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5",
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "contentUrl": null,
        "content": "{\"$schema\":\"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json\",\"version\":\"1.5\",\"type\":\"AdaptiveCard\",\"body\":[{\"type\":\"Container\",\"style\":\"emphasis\",\"items\":[{\"type\":\"TextBlock\",\"text\":\"TheEYorganizationtodayannouncesthedetailsofthe52womenfounders\",\"wrap\":true},{\"type\":\"ColumnSet\",\"columns\":[{\"style\":\"default\",\"width\":\"stretch\",\"items\":[{\"type\":\"ColumnSet\",\"columns\":[{\"items\":[{\"type\":\"Image\",\"width\":\"200px\",\"url\":\"https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th/id/OIP._awI5wQIVTy1k8QdHtpSWQHaEK?w=292&h=180&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=1.3&pid=1.7\"}],\"type\":\"Column\",\"width\":\"auto\"},{\"items\":[{\"type\":\"TextBlock\",\"size\":\"Medium\",\"weight\":\"Bolder\",\"text\":\"SomeText\",\"wrap\":true},{\"type\":\"TextBlock\",\"size\":\"Medium\",\"weight\":\"Bolder\",\"text\":\"[https://adaptivecards.io](https://adaptivecards.io)\",\"wrap\":true}],\"type\":\"Column\",\"width\":\"auto\"}]}],\"minHeight\":\"100px\",\"type\":\"Column\"}]}]}]}",
        "name": null,
        "thumbnailUrl": null
    }
],
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2022-11-18T12:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
},
"end": {
    "dateTime": "2022-11-18T12:30:00",
    "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
},
"location": {
    "displayName": "Harry's Bar"
},
"attendees": [
    {
        "emailAddress": {
            "address": "xero.01234@contoso.com",
            "name": "Orex"
        },
        "type": "required"
    }
],
"isOnlineMeeting": true,
"onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"}
```

Using above body, I am getting below error

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "UnableToDeserializePostBody",
    "message": "were unable to deserialize "
}}
```

As I understand this has something to do with the JSON I am passing as content inside attachment, I want to know if calendar invites endpoint supports adaptive card or not or is there any way, we can send adaptive card (using .NET SDK) to mail or events in outlook

Thanks, in advance

Comment: i'm afraid that calendar event attachment doesn't support Adaptive card... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/attachment?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can send actionable messages via emails only, see [Supported scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email#supported-scenarios) for more information.